# Unix File Permissions issue with Jenkins CI and Github

Tags: unix, github, jenkins, permissions

I am in the process of installing Jenkins to push changes made to a Github repo to a "live" repo on my server.
I have installed Jenkins on my Ubuntu server and using its web interface I have installed the Github, Git and Github API plugins. I've also created a build task in Jenkins which runs some shell commands when Github detects that a push has been made to its repo.

The commands are running but I seem to be hitting a permissions issue. I get the following error in the Jenkins Console:

```
+ git pull origin master
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The parent directory for the site (and all its subdirectories) is owned by a user "james" who belongs to a group "sudo". Jenkins has its own user "jenkins" who I have since added to the group "sudo". As "jenkins" and "james" are both "sudo" members and the group has permission to write, I am unsure why this error would be occuring?

Answer (score 1):

[Adding a user to the group `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/q/2214/5470) does not make that user member of the same group as the one protecting the `.git` folder.

It just allows `jenkins` or `james` to be added to the `sudoers`, and executing commands (specified in said `sudoers`) as `root`.

You need to check which group is protecting `.git`, or if it is the `root` group, modify the `jenkins` script in order to `sudo git pull origin master`.

The [OP James Howell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838685/james-howell) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796710/unix-file-permissions-issue-with-jenkins-ci-and-github/35813338?noredirect=1#comment59324996_35813338):

> I ended up changing the group owner of the directory to "`jenkins`" of which the `jenkins` user is already a member.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Von. I ended up changing the group owner of the directory to "jenkins" of which the jenkins user is already a member.

Comment: @JamesHowell Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.